# Spartacus - Error occurred while trying to proxy request

Tags: spartacus-storefront

when doing yarn start in spartacus application at localhost , I am getting following error:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /rest/v2/electronics-spa/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=homepage&lang=en&curr=USD from localhost:4200 to https://localhost:
9002 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I have pretty standard proxy.bankend.js file. Any suggestions what i can investigate ?
I already tested backend is reachable via url directly.

Regards,
Archit

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with this situation. Usualy this error happens when the endpoint I an trying to proxy to is not reachable.

Looking at the error I can see your request is still going to `https://localhost:9002` so I believe it's possible your proxy might not be picked up.

You should make sure that you specified the proxy config correctly. It can be done in your `package.json` by modifying the start script: `"start": " ng serve --proxy-config proxy/proxy.backend.js",` (in this case my proxy is in a proxy folder).

Hope this helps!